Sequences formed by picking cards from 52 face down in a row
Place 52 cards from a deck face down in a line. Turn the first card, and then move number of cards further equivalent to the face value of the opened card. Now open the card that you land on and continue the same process till you get to the end of the deck (meaning the last card, beyond which when you try to move by face value of the card, you would run out of cards). Mark the last card that was opened. Now, if I do the same process, starting not from the first card but any of the next 9 cards (card numbers 2-10), what are the chances of my last card being the same as yours?
Consider face value of face cards as the following:
J - 11
Q - 12
K - 13
A - 1
I tried simplifying it to a game of 13 cards with all cards of one suit and writing code to brute force the possibilities, but it didn't really work.
Current approach: Define $\mathit p$
as the starting position and $\mathit V_i$
as the value of the card flipped on the $\mathit i$'th move of the game.
For the case where we start at 1, the sequence is:
$$\mathit A_1=p+V_1+V_2+V_3+...$$
until $\mathit A1$
becomes greater than 52.
If, at any point, for any $\mathit A_i$, our sequence coincides with a value at any point in any sub-value of $\mathit A_1$, the sequences become the same from that point. I'm not sure how to move forward with analysing the probabilities of that happening.

You might be interested in reading about the Kruskal Count.

When you say "what are the chances of my last card being the same as yours?", are we comparing card values or card positions?
